Number of $k$-element linearly equivalence classes of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^3$
Work over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0, 1\}$. Say that two sets $S , T \subseteq {\mathbb{F}_2}^3$ are linearly equivalent if there exists an invertible $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that $A \cdot S = T$, where $A \cdot S = \{Ax \in {\mathbb{F}_2}^3 : \, x \in S\}$. For each $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots, 8$, how many equivalence classes of $k$-element subsets of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^3$ are there?
I can work out the answer for small $k$. Say denote by $a(k)$ the number of non-linearly equivalent $k$-element subsets of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^3$.
For $k = 0$, the only $0$-element subset is $\emptyset$. So $a(0) = 1$.
For $k = 1$, the set $\{(0, 0, 0)\}$ is in a class of its own. For any two vectors $x, y \neq 0$, the singletons $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are linearly equivalent. Thus $a(1) = 2$.
For $k = 2$, we have $\{(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)\}$ and $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}$ as representatives. Any set $\{x, y\}$ of 2 distinct nonzero vectors is linearly independent and thus linearly equivalent to $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}$. Thus $a(2) = 2$.
For $k = 3$, we have $\{(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}$, $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$ and $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)\}$ as representatives. A given set $\{x, y, z\}$ of 3 distinct nonzero vectors is either linearly independent or linearly dependent. If $\{x, y, z\} \subset {\mathbb{F}_2}^3 \setminus \{0\}$ is linearly independent, then it is a basis and hence linearly equivalent to $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$. On the other hand, if $\{x, y, z\} \subset {\mathbb{F}_2}^3 \setminus \{0\}$ is linearly dependent, then in fact $x + y + z = 0$ and the set is linearly equivalent to $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)\}$. Thus $a(3) = 3$.

If $A$ takes $S$ to $T$ then it takes the complement of $S$ to the complement of $T$. So you just need to deal with $k=4$ and you're done.

As the learned ancient mathematician said in a comment, it suffices to handle the case of subsets of exactly four vectors. We also observe that if $S$ and $T$ are linearly equivalent, then they either both contain the zero vector or neither does.
Recycling their idea, we see that it suffices to tally the equivalence classes of quartets containing the zero vector, for their complements (within $\Bbb{F}_2^3$) form exactly the classes of the other type.
So we can assume that, in addition to $(0,0,0)$, the set $S$ contains three other vectors.
Hint: Show that those three other (non-zero) vectors are either linearly independent, or the set $S$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{F}_2^3$.

In a higher dimensional space over $\Bbb{F}_2$, when studying some combinatorial properties of the Reed-Muller codes, similar thinking is required. Subsets containing exactly four vectors are either affinely independent or affinely dependent. In the latter case they form a coset of a $2$-dimensional subspace, when we have a formula for their number. It is a bit more difficult, but not unduly taxing, to enumerate the affinely independent quartets.

Thank you, Jyrki. Representatives of 4-element sets containing the zero vector are {0, i, j, k} and {0, i, j, i + j}. By your correspondence between 4-element subsets containing 0 and 4-element subsets not contaning 0, we get a(4) = 4.

Correct, @ColinTan.

Here's an explanation for ancient mathematician's comment.
The equivalence relation you describe has as equivalence classes the $G$-orbits in $2^{\mathbb{F}_2^3}$ under the action of $G=\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$. This action can be restricted to the $k$-sized subsets in $2^{\mathbb{F}_2^3}$, we will denote them by $\binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}$. The number of equivalence classes in $\binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}$ can be calculated by Burnside's lemma (which is wrongly attributed to him): If $\binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}/G$ is the set of $G$-orbits in $\binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}$, then $$|\binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}/G|=\sum\limits_{g\in G} |X_k^g|$$ where $X_k^g=\{x\in \binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}\mid gx=x\}$. If $g\in G$ fixes $S\in \binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}$, then it also fixes $\mathbb{F}_2^3\setminus S=:S^c$ and vice versa, i.e. $$|\{x\in \binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}\mid gx=x\}|=|\{x\in \binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{8-k}\mid gx=x\}|$$ which means $$|\binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{k}/G|=\sum\limits_{g\in G} |X_k^g|=\sum\limits_{g\in G} |X_{8-k}^g|=|\binom{\mathbb{F}_2^3}{8-k}/G|.$$

While you can apply Burnside's Lemma here, I'd favor the elementary explanation "$S$ mapped to $T$ iff complement of $S$ mapped to complement of $T$" given above by ancient mathematician.
